# How to hit like for a facebook POST using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

i'm currently using Facebook Graph API to like a post in facebook.
As described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes
here's my code:

```
FB.api(
"/{object-id}/likes",
"POST",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
```

);

I have the publish_actions permission and I have user token also, but the error was

```
FB.__globalCallbacks.f151265214({"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200}});
```

Can somebody help? kinda desperate right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't gather the `publish_actions` permission upon login to your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes/#publish

You need this permission to post a object like for a specific user.

Comment: I have the publish_actions permission. what else have gone wrong?

Comment: I guess that's not true. Echo the access token and check it via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken Then, you'll see in the `Scopes` result whether the permission is active for that specific access token.